# Typescript: How do you add a type declaration to the severity property in React Alert?

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

I've created a type declaration object for the data that is coming in, but no matter what I seem to try and define as the type for the property "severity", it's upset. What it wants (as shown below) doesn't seem to be an option. I was just wondering if there is a type I can use besides "any" that would work for this ? Or, because it is custom, any is my only option?

Here's what I have that is throwing the below error:

```
type ticketData = {
  name: string;
  title: string;
  onClose: () => void;
  message: string[];
}
```

[image]

https://mui.com/components/snackbars/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to mention any of these below options for colors provided by muiAlert:

```
name: 'success' | 'info' | 'warning' | 'error' | undefined
```

check api Link - https://mui.com/api/alert/